# Simpler method for decoding JSON from multiple services in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, decoding, decodable

## Premise

I have a `struct` that conforms to `Decodable`, so it can decode JSON from a variety of responses via `init(from:)`. For each type of JSON response I expect to decode, I have an `enum` that conforms to `CodingKey`.

## Example

Here's a simplified example, which can be dropped into a Swift playground:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Services -

struct Service1 {}
struct Service2 {}

// MARK: - Person Model -

struct Person {
    let name: String
}

extension Person: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "name"
    }

    enum Service2CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "person_name"
    }

    // And so on through service n...

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        switch decoder.userInfo[.service] {
        case is Service1.Type:
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        case is Service2.Type:
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Service2CodingKeys.self)
            name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        // And so on through service n...
        default:
            fatalError("Missing implementation for service.")
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - CodingUserInfoKey -

extension CodingUserInfoKey {
    static let service = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "service")!
}

// MARK: - Responses -

// The JSON response from service 1.
let service1JSONResponse = """
[
    {
        "name": "Peter",
    }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

// The JSON response from service 2.
let service2JSONResponse = """
[
    {
        "person_name": "Paul",
    }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

// And so on through service n... where other services have JSON responses with keys of varied names ("full_name", "personName").

// MARK: - Decoding -

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

decoder.userInfo[.service] = Service1.self
let service1Persons = try decoder.decode([Person].self, from: service1JSONResponse)

decoder.userInfo[.service] = Service2.self
let service2Persons = try decoder.decode([Person].self, from: service2JSONResponse)
```

## Problem

The problem I'm running into is that I have a lot of different services that I needed to decode responses from, and a model with many more properties than this simplified example. As the number of services increases, so does the number of cases needed to decode those responses.

## Question

How can I simplify my `init(from:)` implementation to reduce all this code duplication?

## Attempts

I've tried storing the correct `CodingKey.Type` for each service and passing that into `container(keyedBy:)`, but I get this error:

> Cannot invoke 'container' with an argument list of type '(keyedBy: CodingKey.Type)'.

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let codingKeyType: CodingKey.Type

    switch decoder.userInfo[.service] {
    case is Service1.Type: codingKeyType = CodingKeys.self
    case is Service2.Type: codingKeyType = Service2CodingKeys.self
    default: fatalError("Missing implementation for service.")
    }

    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: codingKeyType) // ← Error
    name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
}
```

Comment: Move the switch to a private method that returns a container based on a service type. Then decode as normal

Comment: I've actually tried this, but couldn't figure out a working implementation. When I try to pass the correct `CodingKey.Type` for the service into `container(keyedBy:)`, I get this error: `Cannot invoke 'container' with an argument list of type '(keyedBy: CodingKey.Type)'`. Do you have a working example you can share?

Comment: @JWK Can you show your failed attempt?

Comment: @Sweeper Updated the question with my attempt. It's not exactly what you suggested, but I think I run into the same problem either way.

Comment: Whenever you find yourself running different code over a switch, that spells different types to me. I would use multiple struct types, or a class and subclasses.

Comment: On second thought, I don't think this is possible. @JoakimDanielson Are you sure this'd work?

Comment: @Sweeper Apologies, I meant what @Joakim Danielson suggested :) @matt Can you clarify? Do you mean more models conforming to `Decodable` with different `init(from:)` implementations? I see that resulting in a lot more code duplication than my current approach.

Comment: I have tried it now in a playground and it wasn't as easy as I first believed mainly due to the `KeyedDecodingContainer` type that requires the correct CodingKey enum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to solve this with CodingKeys and an increasingly complicated `init`, I suggest composing it via a protocol:

```
protocol PersonLoader: Decodable {
    var name: String { get }
    // additional properties
}

extension Person {
    init(loader: PersonLoader) {
        self.name = loader.name
        // additional properties, but this is one-time
    }
}
```

Alternately, particularly if Person is a read-only simple data object, you could just make Person a protocol, and then you could avoid this extra copying step.

You can then define the interfaces for each service independently:

```
struct Service1Person: PersonLoader {
    let name: String
}

struct Service2Person: PersonLoader {
    let person_name: String

    var name: String { person_name }
}
```

And then map into Persons when you're done:

```
let service2Persons = try decoder.decode([Service2Person].self,
                                         from: service2JSONResponse)
    .map(Person.init)
```

If you went with a protocol-only approach, it would look like this instead:

```
protocol Person: Decodable {
    var name: String { get }
    // additional properties
}

struct Service1Person: Person {
    let name: String
}

struct Service2Person: Person {
    var name: String { person_name }
    let person_name: String
}

let service2Personsx = try decoder.decode([Service2Person].self,
                                         from: service2JSONResponse) as [Person]
```

Comment: Thanks, @Rob Napier. I am dealing with simple, read-only objects, so this makes sense. However, wouldn’t it still be preferable to stick with `CodingKey`? It avoids having to add properties with naming schemes like `person_name`. It should also be unnecessary to write any `init(from:)` implementations if each type specifies the appropriate keys. In my reply to @matt, I was quick to overlook this last point. While this approach requires many more types, the resulting code is arguably cleaner than a giant switch statement where each case duplicates explicit decoding logic.

Comment: Oh, certainly you could implement `Service2Person` with a CodingKey instead of named properties. My reason for doing it this way is that if only a few properties are renamed out of many, then I believe it will require much less code (CodingKeys have to duplicate every property name; this approach only adds extra code when there's a difference). But a key point of the protocols is that the implementation detail doesn't matter. You can do it any way that is convenient for that service; you don't need one universal solution.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Without a bunch of custom per-service (or per-service type) functionality in `Person`'s init(from:), I think it would be difficult to do. You can't pass custom `CodingKey`-conformant enums into `decoder.container(keyedBy:)` because it is generic over the type of that enum.

One way you could do it is by using a custom key decoding strategy and perform the mapping from a dictionary or by a function in the custom key decoding method/closure.

In the example below, I've used an enum to represent the services. The mapping dictionary is keyed off the enum case, so reflects the service/service type key mapping. Hopefully, this can serve as a useful roadmap for your more complex real-world use case.

```swift
import Foundation

// MARK: - Custom Key Decoding -

struct MyCodingKey: CodingKey {
    var stringValue: String
    var intValue: Int?

    init?(stringValue: String) {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
        self.intValue = nil
    }

    init?(intValue: Int) {
        self.stringValue = String(intValue)
        self.intValue = intValue
    }
}

// MARK: - Services -

enum Services: String {
    case service1
    case service2
}

extension Services {

    var mapping: [String:String] {
        switch self {
        case .service1: return [:]
        case .service2: return ["person_name": "name"]
        }
    }

    func getPersons(jsonData: Data) throws -> [Person] {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .custom { (keys: [CodingKey]) -> CodingKey in
            let lastKey = keys.last!
            guard lastKey.intValue == nil else {
                return MyCodingKey(intValue: lastKey.intValue!)!
            }
            guard let stringValue = self.mapping[lastKey.stringValue] else {
                return lastKey
            }

            return MyCodingKey(stringValue: stringValue)!
        }

        let persons = try decoder.decode([Person].self, from: jsonData)
        return persons
    }
}

// MARK: - Person Model -

struct Person: Decodable {
    let name: String
}

// MARK: - Responses -

// The JSON response from service 1.
let service1JSONResponse = """
[ {  "name": "Peter", } ]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

// The JSON response from service 2.
let service2JSONResponse = """
[ { "person_name": "Paul", } ]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

// MARK: - Sample Calls -

print((try? Services.service1.getPersons(jsonData: service1JSONResponse))!)
print((try? Services.service2.getPersons(jsonData: service2JSONResponse))!)
```

Comment: This is clever. I wasn't sure how to implement a custom `keyDecodingStrategy`, so this is a useful example for me. That said, moving all the decoding logic up to `Services` as opposed to on an individual type (or individual types in @Rob Napier's example) may not be an ideal pattern for my app. I will think this answer over more.

Comment: I thought the idea was that you didn't want to have to reimplement the decoding for each service. In this solution, only the differences between what is modeled in the `Person` type (or whatever other types you're using)  and the service response would need to be accounted for (that's why there's only an empty dictionary for the `.service1` mapping. It seemed to make sense to note these differences at the service level.

Comment: I see. The selected answer does actually avoid needing explicit `init(from:)` decoding implementations. The decoding differences can be accounted for using properties on each service type or conforming the type to `CodingKey`. I think that is my preference, especially when dealing with responses that are more disparate and complex than this example, but I do see where you're coming from.